# CheckListBox inside PopupWindow

Tags: python, wxpython, popupwindow

I am trying to figure out why the wx.CheckListBox doesn't work correctly inside a popup window. The scrollbars work, but I am unable to select anything. I have tried multiple types of popup windows and still get the same behavior.

Any ideas for a workaround besides using a Frame?

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Hello World')
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        

        
        #self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos=(5, 5))
        my_btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Press Me', pos=(5, 55))
        my_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnShowPopupTransient)

        self.Show()


    def OnShowPopupTransient(self, evt):
        sampleList = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five',
                      'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven',
                      'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen']
        win = TestTransientPopup(self,
                                    wx.SIMPLE_BORDER,
                                    sampleList)

        
        # Show the popup right below or above the button
        # depending on available screen space...
        btn = evt.GetEventObject()
        pos = btn.ClientToScreen( (0,0) )
        sz =  btn.GetSize()
        win.Position(pos, (0, sz[1]))

        win.Popup()

class TestTransientPopup(wx.PopupTransientWindow):
    """Adds a bit of text and mouse movement to the wx.PopupWindow"""
    def __init__(self, parent, style, sampleList):
        wx.PopupTransientWindow.__init__(self, parent, style)
    
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour("#FFB6C1")
        
        lb = wx.CheckListBox(panel, -1, (80, 50), wx.DefaultSize, sampleList)
        
        btn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Press Me")
        spin = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, -1, "Hello", size=(100,-1))
        #btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(lb, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(spin, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        sizer.Fit(panel)
        sizer.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Works for me, Linux, 4.0.4 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify your platform or version of wxPython but on Linux wxPython '4.1.1 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.1.5' the following code appears to work as expected. (Unless you expected something else)

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(parent=None, title='Hello World')
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        my_btn = wx.Button(panel, label='Press Me', pos=(5, 55))
        my_btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnShowPopupTransient)
        self.Show()

    def OnShowPopupTransient(self, evt):
        sampleList = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five',
                      'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten', 'eleven',
                      'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen']
        win = TestTransientPopup(self, wx.BORDER_SIMPLE, sampleList)
        # Show the popup right below or above the button
        # depending on available screen space...
        btn = evt.GetEventObject()
        pos = btn.ClientToScreen( (0, 0) )
        sz =  btn.GetSize()
        win.Position(pos, (0, sz[1]))
        win.Popup(focus=self)


class TestTransientPopup(wx.PopupTransientWindow):
    """Adds a bit of text and mouse movement to the wx.PopupWindow"""
    def __init__(self, parent, style, sampleList):
        wx.PopupTransientWindow.__init__(self, parent, style)
        self.SetSize((150, 300))    
        panel = wx.Panel(self, size=(150, 300))
        panel.SetBackgroundColour("dark grey")
        
        self.lb = wx.CheckListBox(panel, -1, choices=sampleList)
        
        btn = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Press Me")
        self.spin = wx.SpinCtrl(panel, -1, "10")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.lb, 1, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.spin, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

    def OnButton(self, event):
        checked_items = self.lb.GetCheckedStrings()
        spin_value = self.spin.GetValue()
        print("Selected items", checked_items)
        print("Spin value", spin_value)
        self.Dismiss()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: My apologies, I am on Windows. On my system it, shows correctly, but nothing can be checked or unchecked. I did some research and it appears a few others have had the same issues. I ended up making a custom dialog class and it is now working correctly. I will update my post with the custom dialog. I will mark this as the correct answer.